# How to take in, modify and replace a line in a text file?

Tags: c++

I have a file called accounts.txt where it is formated like so:

```
firstName lastName | cardNum | pin | balance | status | dateCreated
--------------------------------------------------------------------
John Smith | 8947 | 1234 | 0 | open | 2016-03-29.12:30:01
Mike Casey | 9322 | 1111 | 0 | open | 2016-03-29.12:30:11
```

I want to be able to loop through the file and change a specific entry for example if I want to go to cardNum = 9322 and change the balance, I'll have to search for the third vertical bar ('|') and take in the digits until the fourth vertical bar ('|'), edit the number and re-output right?

The problem is I'm new to c++ and I'm not sure how I can locate the third ('|') and edit the value after it then re-output.  I know I'll have to read in the whole file then output to a new file. This is how I create a new account:

```
void AccountHandler::createAccount() //Account creation function
{
//create account in format: { First Last | cardNum | pin | balance | status | accInfo }

struct bankAccount newacc;
ofstream accounts;
string tempPin1, tempPin2;

if (!accounts.is_open())
{
    accounts.open("accounts.txt", ios::app);
}

std::cout << "Thanks for choosing to bank with ATM406, let's get started!" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Please enter your name (First Last): ";

//SET NAME ON ACCOUNT

getline (cin, newacc.name);

//SET SECURITY PIN ON ACCOUNT

for (;;)
{
    std::cout << "\nPlease enter a four-digit pin to secure your account: ";
    getline (cin, tempPin1);

    std::cout << "\nPlease re-enter your four-digit pin for verification: ";
    getline (cin, tempPin2);

    if (tempPin1 != tempPin2) //Pins did not match
    {
        std::cout << "The pins did not match!" << std::endl;
    }
    else //Pins match
    {
        newacc.pin = tempPin1;
        break;
    }
}

//ASSIGN A RANDOM FOUR-DIGIT CARD NUMBER FROM 1000-9999

srand(time(NULL));
ostringstream convert;
convert << rand() % 9000 + 1000;
newacc.cardNum = convert.str();

//ASSIGN A STARTING BALANCE OF 0$

newacc.balance = "0";

//CREATE DATE OF ACCOUNT CREATION

newacc.accInfo = currentDateTime();

//SET STATUS OF ACCOUNT

newacc.LOCKED = false;
string status;

if (newacc.LOCKED == false)
    status = "open";

//PUSH INFO TO TEXT FILE

accounts << newacc.name << " | " << newacc.cardNum << " | " << newacc.pin << " | " << newacc.balance << " | " 
    << status << " | " << newacc.accInfo << std::endl;

//CLOSE FILE

accounts.close();

}
```

I'm looking to create a function like:

```
struct bankAccount AccountHandler::getAccount(string cardNum)
{

}
```

in order to retrieve account info but I'm stuck with finding info from the file.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The easiest way is to read your file completely and create a `std::vector<bankAccount>`, then operate on the entries of that vector, and write it back in whole.

Comment: @KenWhite Not really that dupe.

Comment: I realize this isn't what you're asking, but why is this in a text file rather than e.g. a sqlite db?

Comment: @JustinR I realize operating with a db would probably simplify things but like I said I'm new to C++ and I'm not sure where I would start with that

Comment: I think you will find it is actually be much easier to accomplish this with a db than with a text file. Have a look at https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html

Answer (score 0):

Consider how this can be achieved with [easyLambda](https://github.com/haptork/easyLambda) library.

```
ezl::rise(
  ezl::readFile<string, array<int, 3>, array<string, 2>>(fileName)
    .colSeparator("|"))
.map<2>([](array<int,3> cardPinBal) { // 2nd column selected for lambda
  if (cardPinBal[0] == 9322) cardPinBal[2] = newBal;
  return cardPinBal;
}).colsTransform().dump("updatedInfo.txt")
.run();
```

Here, readFile reads the data file, the types are for columns on every row. It is implemented using `readLine` for reading rows and string splitting on colSeparators for each row. The strings are converted to types using boost `lexical cast` however `stoi` and family can work equally well.
The function in the map is applied to every row (for selected cols, here 2nd col). ColsTransform makes sure that the columns update with returned value without reordering.

You may consider using the library for general data processing tasks.